# Is it Makruh to remove natural vegetation from a grave?

Tags: practical-islam, grave

I came across the below today:

> Grass, etc. should be placed on the grave of the deceased, as long as
> it remains fresh it will continue to do tasbīh, it is for this reason
> that removing fresh grass from the graveyard is disliked (makrūh),
> just as it is mentioned in Radd al-Muhtār in the chapter of funerals,
>
> “قطع النبات الرطب والحشیش من المقبرۃ دون الیابس کما فی البحر والدرر
> وشرح المنیۃ وعللہ فی الامداد بانہ مادام رطباً یسبح اﷲ تعالٰی  فیونس
> المیّت وتنزل بذکرہ الرحمۃ ونحوہ فی الخانیۃ انتھی”
>
> “It is disliked to cut fresh grass from the graveyards, not dry grass,
> just as it is stated in al-Bahr, al-Durr, Sharh al-Munyah, and its
> reason is mentioned in Imdād; as long as it remains fresh it continues
> to do tasbīh of Allāh (Most High), due to which the deceased
> experiences ease, and something similar is mentioned in Khāniyah.”
>
> [Radd al-Muhtār, Bāb Salāt al-Janāiz, Volume 1, pg 606]

Can someone provide more details on the subject.

Comment: This is related to the [sahih hadith in "Sahih al-Bukhari 1361 - Funerals (Al-Janaa'iz) - كتاب الجنائز - Sayings and Teachings of Prophet Muhammad (صلى الله عليه و سلم)](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1361). But for example if the roots of the vegetation may harm the buried person, it is permissible to remove it.

Comment: Tnx but I'm trying to search for natural growing vegetation. In this Hadith, it states "He then took a green leaf of a date-palm tree split it into two pieces and fixed one on each grave".